# tensorflow just returning the 1st argument

Tags: python, tensorflow

Exactly what the title says:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
   a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
   b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
   c = a+b
   print(session.run(c, feed_dict={a:3,b:2}))
```

The above code was should print 5 when run. But it always prints whatever is assigned to a. This is the same result even if use `tf.add(a,b)` instead of `a+b`.

The strange thing is that above code is malfunctioning only on one computer. It works fine everywhere else.

Is this some sort of a configuration issue? Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

**Background Information:** 
I am using the GPU version of tensorflow.
I have installed this using conda: `conda install tensorflow-gpu`. 
I am running this on docker. 
This works fine if I change the placeholder type to int32

**Update:**
After I restarted the container, the problem disappeared. But I'm still curious to know what could have caused it. And How it can be fixed without restarting the container?

Comment: This does print 5. Have you tested it?

Comment: Your code prints `5.0` on my pc..

Comment: I have tested it. It is printing 3 on my machine. But the strange thing is when I run it on Azure notebooks, It prints 5 there. Updated the question to reflect that.